# Is there any solution to this equation $1-2x\cos(\theta)+x^2=0$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Is there any solution to this  $1-2x\cos(\theta)+x^2=0$ and $1-2x^n\cos(n\theta)+x^{2n}$

I found this equation from the book Abraham de Moivre: Setting the stage for classical probability and its application. On page 65, the author states that the solution to this equation is $\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)-i\sin(x)$. How do you derive the solutions?

Comment: The root in $x$ cannot depend on $x$. Did you mean $1 - 2 x \cos(\color{red}{a}) + x^2 = 0$ maybe?

Comment: I find this strange as well, for according to desmo, the minimum value of the first function lies above x axis. This means the function do not have any root.

Comment: The roots of $1 - 2 x \cos(\color{red}{a}) + x^2 = 0$ *are* in fact $\cos(a) \pm i \sin(a)$, but the question as written does not make sense. Maybe post the full quotes around those two statements in the book.

Comment: How do you derive it? And you are right. I mistyped the equation. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Solve the quadratic in $x$.

Comment: Sorry I am kind of stuck at the quadratic formula. Could you help me out?

Comment: Just use the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) for $a \leftarrow 1$, $b \leftarrow -2\cos a$, $c \leftarrow 1$, and remember $\sin^2 a+\cos^2 a = 1$. If that still doesn't work, please post the steps and exactly where you got stuck. P.S. Please also fix the question. The title and $5$ other places are still wrong.

Comment: The solution is just $\frac{\cos(x)-\sqrt{\cos^2-4}}{2}$ and . $\frac{\cos(x)+\sqrt{\cos^2-4}}{2}$ do you get to the final solution in this form?

Comment: Ok, let me try. Thanks

Comment: So the solution is $\frac{2\cos(x)+\sqrt{4cos^2(\theta)-4}}{2}$ and $\frac{2\cos(x)-\sqrt{4cos^2(\theta)-4}}{2}$

Comment: (1) Keep simplifying. Factor our the common factor of $4$ under the square root, and then go further from there. (2) On an unrelated note, it would be nice if you improve your question. Your title says that you're seeking solutions to an equation, but there's no equation in the title, only an expression, since there's no "$=$" sign in it. And the confusion with $x$ and $\theta$, as pointed out in another comment above, should be fixed too.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I am done. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to show that $x=e^{i\theta}$ is a solution to the quadratic without knowing prior that $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may easily figure the complex solutions of 
$$ (x^n-e^{ni\theta})(x^n-e^{-ni\theta}) = 0.$$

Comment: Is there any connection between these equations and de Moivre formula? I have seen proof by induction but so far I have seen no direct derivation from any known trigonometric identities, except from the Euler formula.

Comment: How do you solve this equation together with the second from the OP? I notice I can make a substitution for $e^{ixn}=cos(nx) +isin(nx)$. But how should one proceed to find x?

Comment: This equation follows *directly* from $2\cos\theta = e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}$, which on its turn can be proved through the Maclaurin series of $\exp$ and $\cos$ (both are entire functions).